# How to display the stored image data(mediumblob) along with other data in a .php page

Tags: php, mysql

I have some data stored in a MySQL database.  How to display the stored image data(mediumblob) along with other data in a .php page.

Comment: There is no way anyone could answer that. Please provide more detail. What do the tables look like? What code have you come up with so far?

Comment: That is a very bad practice that you're following. Never store images in database. Only store it's path.

Comment: @asprin If images are not to be stored in a database, what do you do to prevent millions of photos being in one directory? One project I'm working on has a customer table and each customer has 3 pictures and if I just threw them all into one directory; what would you recommend if not put in the database?

Comment: That's again a bad practice. Why would you want to store everything in one folder? You can categorize them based on the customer, can't you?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'pass', 'db'); //Connect to the DB
$res = $db->query('SELECT * FROM `table`'); //Query the DB

while($i = $res->fetch_object()) { //Loop through the images in the DB
    echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,',base64_encode($i->image),'" /><br />'; //Print out each image in the DB  as a base64 encoded string
}
?>
```

You will need to change the `image/jpeg` part to whatever format your images are in. Also, its  better to store the images outside of the database and just store the path to the image in the database (like asprin said).